# SQL query allowing for a space in the value searched

Tags: sql

I am trying to improve a search function to allow for a space when people search involving data from 2 columns in the same table. For example location and keyword ie they search for Townsville marketing.

I tried the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM `partners` 
WHERE location_keywords LIKE '%$result%' 
   OR keywords LIKE '%$result%' 
   OR keywords[&#32]+location_keywords LIKE '%$result%' 
   OR location_keywords[&#32]+keywords LIKE '%$result%'
```

I want it to return all results that contain Townsville, Marketing, Townsville marketing, or marketing townsville.

This throws a syntax error.

Can anyone help me fix this please?

Comment: Could you please show some sample input and expected outcome as tables? Reading your description, I can't replicate why so many conditions are required? Can't you just concat the two columns and check if like result1 or like result2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try adding `keywords` on both sides, because the user can write in any order.

Let's replace spaces with any number of characters - this will allow you to search even if there are a lot of words in the `keywords`, and the user wrote one of them.

Let's convert everything to uppercase so that it does not depend on the case.

```
SELECT * 
FROM `partners` 
WHERE 
UPPER(keywords ||' '|| location_keywords ||' '|| keywords) like Replace(UPPER('%$result%'),' ','%')
```

PS:
Column connection may depend on the database

```
keywords ||' '|| location_keywords ||' '|| keywords
```

or

```
keywords +' '+ location_keywords +' '+ keywords
```

or

```
CONCAT_WS(' ',keywords,location_keywords,keywords)
```

PSS: better if `$result` is prepared more carefully in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following as suggested and it worked exactly as I wanted it to. Thank you so much!

SELECT * FROM `partners` WHERE
UPPER(CONCAT_WS(' ',keywords,location_keywords,keywords)) like Replace(UPPER('%$result%'),' ','%')